# MatLab OOP not changing properties

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a matlab class with property 'next state'.

I have the following function defined in the class:

```
function obj = decideNextAction(obj)
            obj.current_patch_quality
            % Important, rand is redeclared in the two calls. So it may be
            % that rand < current_patch_quality in the first if and greater
            % than in the second if
            if(rand > obj.current_patch_quality)
                obj.next_action = 1;
            elseif(rand < obj.current_patch_quality)
                obj.next_action = 3;
            else
                obj.next_action = 2;
            end   


        end
```

Which should redefine the instance property to 1, 2 or 3. However, I did a few trials and it seems like the function returns a new object with the modified instance, but does not modify the original one. Any advice?

```
>> x = recruit([0 0])

x =

  recruit with properties:

             nest_location: [0 0]
    current_patch_location: []
     current_patch_quality: 0
               next_action: []

>> x.decideNextAction

ans =

     0


ans =

  recruit with properties:

             nest_location: [0 0]
    current_patch_location: []
     current_patch_quality: 0
               next_action: 1

>> x

x =

  recruit with properties:

             nest_location: [0 0]
    current_patch_location: []
     current_patch_quality: 0
               next_action: []

>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `handle class` in `classdef`:

```
classdef myclass < handle
```

If you use `value class`, then it must be:

```
x = x.decideNextAction();
```